# Office 365 error Resource not found for the segment 'MailFolders'

Tags: asp.net, office365, office365api

I am creating functionality in Asp.net webform to display Office 365 mails in one of my page.
Currently I am using Microsoft.Office365.Discovery (v1.0.22) and Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices (v1.0.41.0) nuget package.
I need to display Folder wise total mail coundand total unread count but Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices (v.1.0.41.0) does'n have such functionality.

So i downloaded nugetpackage Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices (v.2.0.1.0) which has properties UnreadItemCount  and TotalItemCount

ex:

```
var folderResult = await outlookServicesClient.Me.MailFolders.ExecuteAsync();
var cnt = folderResult.CurrentPage.ToList()[0].TotalItemCount;
```

but when i call ExecuteAsync() it gives below error:

```
{
   "error":
          {
              "code":"RequestBroker-ParseUri",
              "message":"Resource not found for the segment 'MailFolders'."
          }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with it?

`Added How to use OutlookServicesClient`

```
DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId, new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey), new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            });

            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capabilityName);

            return new OutlookServicesClient(dcr.ServiceEndpointUri,
            async () =>
            {
                var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(dcr.ServiceResourceId, new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey), new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));

                return authResult.AccessToken;
            });
```

and URLs that is used

```
    private static string _discoverySvcResourceId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";
    private static string _discoverySvcEndpointUri = "https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll get that error if you are using the v1 API endpoint. Make sure when you create your `OutlookServicesClient` object you construct it this way:

```
OutlookServicesClient client = 
  new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"), GetToken);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply, according to your answer I'm already using OutlookServicesClient as this way but can you tell me how can you get GetToken while initializing OutlookServicesClient.

Comment: Hi Jason, 
I used hardcoded uri as you said and it worked, but I have one question on that,
according to added code that show how I get OutlookServicesClient, the response of dcr variable contain ServiceEndpointUri as v1.0 uri though I'm sending v2.0 uri at creating DiscoveryClient. so why the response get v1.0 uri.

Comment: Discovery isn't necessary for Outlook, the endpoint is always the one I put there.