# Microsoft.Office365.Discovery - CapabilityDiscoveryResult -> ServiceEndpointUri has wrong URi after using Office 365 V2 DLL

Tags: office365, office365api, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

I was using V1 DLL of Office 365 API for performing calendar operations.
I moved to V2 DLL but I still have Microsoft.Office365.Discovery of version 1.0.22

While creating OutlookServiceClient, I am creating CapabilityDiscoveryResult (dcr)

```
var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("Calendar");
```

Value of dcr.ServiceEndpointUri is still appearing as https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0
[image]
When I changed this URi to v2.0, it worked fine for me.

This is causing the issue while creating an event using V2 DLL

I have removed the DLL's and added them again (just in case if I missed anything) as per the V2 DLL dependencies.

Can you please confirm if this URL is appearing correct or am I missing anything. Also let me know where can I check again.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you setup your DiscoveryService endpoint to be https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you please confirm if this URL is appearing correct or am I missing anything

The return URL is quite expected.

The version of Office 365 API DLL you project is referencing is **irrelevant** of the endpoint URI discovery service returns. You could reference none Office 365 API DLL but still uses the discovery service client. Thus, changing Office 365 API DLL to V2 does not affect the DiscoveryClient return endpoint.

Explicitly using v2.0 service endpoint for Discovery Client does not help either,

```
var discoveryClient = new DiscoveryClient(new Uri(@"https://api.office.com/discovery/v2.0/me/"),
                async () => await GetAccessTokenForResource("https://api.office.com/discovery/"));
```

The difference between v1.0 and v2.0 discovery service endpoint can be found in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/discovery-service-rest-operations).

If you want to use the V2 Office 365 API, it's safe to the hard-coded endpoint "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0", per the post in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153626/office-365-error-resource-not-found-for-the-segment-mailfolders/35156831).

Answer (score 0):

Discovery isn't necessary for Outlook ,you could skip that and create the OutlookServicesClient object like :

```
OutlookServicesClient client = new OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0"),
        async () =>
        {
            //code to get your token
            return token;
        });
```

The outlook endpoint should be "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0" .Check [this demo](https://dev.outlook.com/restapi/tutorial/dotnet) with Microsoft Office 365 Mail, Calendar and Contacts Library v2.0